# IBM Cloud API Docs Tone Analyzer

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I tried to implement :

`curl -u "apikey:{apikey}" "{url}/{method}"
resorce:https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/tone-analyzer`

My question what I need to do? I already have the api key, for example 1234,
and my url is `https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api`

First what is the: `{method}` in the above cURL request and what do I need to do with that?
Question 2 this is correct?:

`curl -u "apikey:1234" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/{method}`

Comment: Format and grammar fixes

Answer (score 1):

In the cURL request below:

```
curl -X GET -u "apikey:{apikey}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21&text=Team,%20I%20know%20that%20times%20are%20tough!%20Product%20sales%20have%20been%20disappointing%20for%20the%20past%20three%20quarters.%20We%20have%20a%20competitive%20product,%20but%20we%20need%20to%20do%20a%20better%20job%20of%20selling%20it!"
```

The {URL} is https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api and {method} is /v3/tone. To under the endpoint, check [this link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/tone-analyzer/using-tone.html#using-the-general-purpose-endpoint)

You are making a GET method call and for this, you need to create a service at https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/tone-analyzer

For more information on how to get an API key, refer to [this link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/tone-analyzer/getting-started.html#gettingStarted)